# remove quotes and squared brackets from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

A second Problem occurs while looping.
The list contains strings in squared brackets:

```
values = [['16.4 '], ['18.06 '], ['16.4 '], ['18.06 ']]
```

But the result should be appear as follows (no squotes, no squared brackets):

```
values = [16.3, 18.06, 16.4, 18.6]
```

the script:

```
name = []
values = []

    import itertools
    import re


    df = open('TESTSOV.csv')
    for i,line in enumerate(itertools.islice(df,10)):
        if "TYPE" in line:
            print('hello')
            name.append(re.findall('NAME= (.*?\s)',line))

        if re.search(r"\bNOMINAL\b",line):
            values.append(re.findall('H= (.*?\s)',line))


    print(name, '\n', values)
```

the .csv document contains:

```
<Set Name= Test>
    < TYPE NAME= Hello >
        <NOMINAL A= B= C= D= E= F= G= 1.10 H= 2.20 I= 3.30 J= >
        <2ND_NOMINAL A= B= C= D= E= F= G= 11.00 H= 22.00 I= 33.00 >

    < TYPE NAME= bye >
        <NOMINAL A= B= C= D= E= F= G= 1.10 H= 2.50 I= 3.30 J= >
        <2ND_NOMINAL A= B= C= D= E= F= G= 11.00 H= 22.00 I= 33.00 >


<END>
```

Comment: `values = [float(v[0]) for v in values]`

Comment: It's not "square brackets", those are *lists*. You'll want to take only *one item* from that list.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the sub list because you are using `re.findall` instead use `re.search` to get the single value from line.

**Ex:**

```
for i,line in enumerate(itertools.islice(df,10)):
    if "TYPE" in line:
        print('hello')
        name.append(re.search('NAME= (.*?\s)',line).group(0))

    if re.search(r"\bNOMINAL\b",line):
        values.append(re.search('H= (.*?\s)',line).group(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below :

```
values = [['16.4 '], ['18.06 '], ['16.4 '], ['18.06 ']]

output = [float(i[0]) for i in values]

print(output)
```